# Ajax.form dropdownlist to change user role

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

Could you give some simple example of how to create form that consists of only dropdownlist?

I want to use it to create admin-side user management to assign users to one role, with aspnet mvc simplemembership. I mean step by step:
- list all registered users (DONE)
- next to their nicks show dropdown list; selected value is user's current role using

> Roles.AddUserToRole(item.UserName, "RoleName");

- by changing dropdown value assign user to new role (overwrite old one) with ajax (don't reload page, just show for few seconds success/error status)

Anyway, I'd like similar example how to do it, it doesn't have to be code I exactly need to produce.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#dropdown").on("change keyup", function() {
     var selected = $(this).val();
     $.post("/Controller/AssignRole", {selectedRole: selected}, function(data) {
           //data is the value returned by your action method. 
           //example: partial view, or status message

          $("#status").html(data); //success message
     });
});
```